# Uno platform: invoke UI update from async thread

Tags: async-await, uno-platform

I have an `async` member which ultimately needs to invoke some UI updates, after getting some data from a server.

I think I need something like `BeginInvokeOnMainThread`, or `Dispatcher.Invoke`, but neither of these appear to be recognized in the Uno context.

Here's the essence of what I have:

```
public async Task LoadList()
{
  ...
  // get data
  Uri uri = new Uri("https://...");
  response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

  // display
  BeginInvokeOnMainThread () =>
  {
    ... update the UI ...
  });
}
```

But I get the error `CS0103 The name 'BeginInvokeOnMainThread' does not exist in the current context UnoTest.Droid, UnoTest.UWP, UnoTest.Wasm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BeginInvokeOnMainThread` / `Dispatcher.Invoke` / `Control.Invoke` were never a good idea.

Uno should have a `SynchronizationContext` that is [automatically used by `await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), so manual thread marshaling should not be necessary:

```
public async Task LoadList()
{
  ...
  // get data
  Uri uri = new Uri("https://...");
  response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

  // display
  ... update the UI ...
}
```

Comment: Where can I find an explanation on this ? I don't understand how synchronous code can suddenly become async. I'm making the assumption that anything affecting the UI has something built-in which switches over to the UI thread.

Comment: Not working: I get a syntax error when I try to assign to a UI element, e.g. Folder.Text = "asdf"; It gives me "the error The name 'Folder' does not exist in the current context."

Comment: I retract that :) It works. I had to fix something seemingly unrelated, exit VS, restart VS, and then it built. Thanks so much !

Comment: @PeriHartman: Take a look at the link in my answer; it explains how `await` works with regards to `SynchronizationContext`. The code isn't *synchronous* (blocking a thread). The code is *asynchronous* (not blocking a thread), but also *serial* (one statement at a time). That's the whole point of the `async`/`await` keywords.

Comment: Thanks for your link, I think I follow. Using a UI thread caller as an example: when it calls an async method, execution continues synchronously until it hits an await. At that point (normally) it will save the current stack and env in a "context", clear the stack, and let the UI thread handle the next UI action. Meanwhile the await function begins on a new thread. When it completes, the UI thread is reinvoked, using the saved context to build the stack back to its point at the await. Execution continues synchronously until another await or the method returns. Essentially correct ?

Comment: @PeriHartman: No. There is no separate thread, and the stack is not saved/restored. `await` will actually *return* to its caller.

Comment: ok, then I'm completely not understanding something fundamental. Can we chat for a moment ?

Comment: At an await, I see two possibilities: either the thread completes (with a mechanism to save state) or it is blocked. The UI thread should never be blocked. And, I think you're telling me the thread doesn't complete, either.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just heading out camping for the weekend. Perhaps reading through [this link](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) again or the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) may help?